# After reboot, nvidia drivers are missing, how can I find out what happened?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have had a stable install of Nvidia drivers 410.78  working with my Nvidia Quadro RTX4000 Graphic Cards on my Ubuntu 18.04 for over a year now. Because of previous bad experiences with automatic upgrades breaking the system, I blacklisted any upgrades to the graphic drivers.

Today I rebooted my computer, after which the whole link to nvidia drivers and the GPUs seems to be lost. Nvidia-smi doesn't find any drivers

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

there is no folder /proc/driver/nvidia (only /proc/driver/rtc ), the program NVIDIA X Server Settings shows nothing at all.

I checked /var/log/dpkg.log  and  /var/log/apt/history.log  for any unattended upgrades related to the graphic drivers but I see none.

This is really upsetting as whenever it has happened before, I ended up having to practically install everything from scratch, a process which is painful and very time consuming.

Is there any way I can find out what happened? Where did the nvidia drivers go? Why the reboot destroy/replaced them? And most importantly, how can I revert back to the way the system was an hour ago?  Any pointers and help much appreciated.

Edit: output of  "dkms status"

```
nvidia, 410.78, 4.15.0-1027-oem, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 410.78, 4.15.0-1101-oem, x86_64: installed
oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22, 0.1, 4.15.0-1027-oem, x86_64: installed
oem-ethernet-intel-igb-lp1805326-5.3.5.22, 0.1, 4.15.0-1101-oem, x86_64: installed
```

Output of
zgrep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '  | grep linux

```
/var/log/dpkg.log.10.gz:2020-03-18 06:57:16 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1076:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.10.gz:2020-03-18 06:57:21 linux-headers-4.15.0-1076-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.10.gz:2020-03-18 06:57:24 linux-modules-4.15.0-1076-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.10.gz:2020-03-18 06:57:30 linux-image-4.15.0-1076-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-11 07:01:17 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1069:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-11 07:01:20 linux-headers-4.15.0-1069-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-11 07:01:22 linux-modules-4.15.0-1069-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-11 07:01:27 linux-image-4.15.0-1069-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-20 06:41:24 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1073:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-20 06:41:28 linux-headers-4.15.0-1073-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-20 06:41:30 linux-modules-4.15.0-1073-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.11.gz:2020-02-20 06:41:35 linux-image-4.15.0-1073-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-03 06:47:23 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1103:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-03 06:47:30 linux-headers-4.15.0-1103-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-03 06:47:33 linux-modules-4.15.0-1103-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-03 06:47:45 linux-image-4.15.0-1103-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:38 linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:40 linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:41 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:45 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-58:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:45 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:50 linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:52 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.1:2020-12-13 06:59:53 linux-generic-hwe-18.04:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-08 06:17:31 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1066:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-08 06:17:35 linux-headers-4.15.0-1066-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-08 06:17:37 linux-modules-4.15.0-1066-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-08 06:17:42 linux-image-4.15.0-1066-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-31 06:48:19 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1067:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-31 06:48:22 linux-headers-4.15.0-1067-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-31 06:48:24 linux-modules-4.15.0-1067-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2020-01-31 06:48:30 linux-image-4.15.0-1067-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-06 06:59:19 linux-modules-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-06 06:59:23 linux-image-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-06 06:59:24 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-06 06:59:32 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-59:all
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-06 06:59:37 linux-headers-5.4.0-59-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-08 06:53:27 linux-modules-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-08 06:53:29 linux-image-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-08 06:53:29 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-08 06:53:33 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60:all
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-08 06:53:37 linux-headers-5.4.0-60-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-15 06:15:31 linux-modules-5.4.0-62-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-15 06:15:35 linux-image-5.4.0-62-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-15 06:15:36 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-62-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-15 06:15:46 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-62:all
/var/log/dpkg.log:2021-01-15 06:15:56 linux-headers-5.4.0-62-generic:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2020-11-12 06:29:47 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1101:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2020-11-12 06:29:55 linux-headers-4.15.0-1101-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2020-11-12 06:29:58 linux-modules-4.15.0-1101-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2020-11-12 06:30:08 linux-image-4.15.0-1101-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-14 06:24:07 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1099:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-14 06:24:16 linux-headers-4.15.0-1099-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-14 06:24:19 linux-modules-4.15.0-1099-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-14 06:24:28 linux-image-4.15.0-1099-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-21 06:30:41 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1100:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-21 06:30:47 linux-headers-4.15.0-1100-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-21 06:30:50 linux-modules-4.15.0-1100-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.3.gz:2020-10-21 06:30:59 linux-image-4.15.0-1100-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-03 06:31:11 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1094:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-03 06:31:15 linux-headers-4.15.0-1094-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-03 06:31:17 linux-modules-4.15.0-1094-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-03 06:31:22 linux-image-4.15.0-1094-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-09 06:47:10 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1096:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-09 06:47:14 linux-headers-4.15.0-1096-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-09 06:47:16 linux-modules-4.15.0-1096-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-09 06:47:22 linux-image-4.15.0-1096-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-23 06:43:07 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1097:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-23 06:43:11 linux-headers-4.15.0-1097-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-23 06:43:13 linux-modules-4.15.0-1097-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2020-09-23 06:43:18 linux-image-4.15.0-1097-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-04 06:23:47 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1091:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-04 06:23:52 linux-headers-4.15.0-1091-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-04 06:23:55 linux-modules-4.15.0-1091-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-04 06:24:00 linux-image-4.15.0-1091-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-23 06:08:13 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1093:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-23 06:08:21 linux-headers-4.15.0-1093-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-23 06:08:24 linux-modules-4.15.0-1093-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.6.gz:2020-07-23 06:08:30 linux-image-4.15.0-1093-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-02 06:19:59 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1081:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-02 06:20:05 linux-headers-4.15.0-1081-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-02 06:20:08 linux-modules-4.15.0-1081-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-02 06:20:15 linux-image-4.15.0-1081-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-10 06:22:46 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1087:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-10 06:22:51 linux-headers-4.15.0-1087-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-10 06:22:54 linux-modules-4.15.0-1087-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-10 06:22:59 linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-27 06:15:50 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1090:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-27 06:15:54 linux-headers-4.15.0-1090-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-27 06:15:57 linux-modules-4.15.0-1090-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.7.gz:2020-06-27 06:16:02 linux-image-4.15.0-1090-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.8.gz:2020-05-01 06:20:04 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1080:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.8.gz:2020-05-01 06:20:08 linux-headers-4.15.0-1080-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.8.gz:2020-05-01 06:20:11 linux-modules-4.15.0-1080-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.8.gz:2020-05-01 06:20:16 linux-image-4.15.0-1080-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2020-04-08 06:01:20 linux-oem-headers-4.15.0-1079:all
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2020-04-08 06:01:23 linux-headers-4.15.0-1079-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2020-04-08 06:01:25 linux-modules-4.15.0-1079-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2020-04-08 06:01:30 linux-image-4.15.0-1079-oem:amd64
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2020-04-16 14:03:23 libselinux1:i386
```

It seems that between then 6 and 15 of January 2021, the kernel 5.4 was installed. This was the first reboot since, so its the possible culprit.

```
uname -r
5.4.0-62-generic
```

Comment: Sounds like a kernel update and the NVIDIA drivers did not install the DKMS drivers that will carry over into a new kernel update.  `dkms status` will show you the drivers installed.  Also, the drivers from either the built in Ubuntu ones or the ones from the `graphics-drivers` PPA will install the DKMS.  One way to tell is to choose Advanced in Grub and go to an older kernel and see if the drivers load there.

Comment: I updated the question with the output of dkms status, this is a useful comment and points to something it hadn't occurred to me. Could you elaborate on those steps you propose? I am not sure exactly how to proceed

Comment: Those are some interesting kernel versions you have installed there, they do not look like default Ubuntu kernels.  I prefer the `graphics-drivers` PPA.  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` which will add it in.  It stays pretty updated and they also test the drivers before they release them into it.  But I do recommend removing the drivers before installing from the PPA.

Comment: @Terrance how can I confirm the theory that there was a kernel update which broke my system? Whatever I had was working until today, so I would start by figuring out what happened, instead of changing the system

Comment: The only thing I can recommend is to boot into a previous kernel.  The DKMS shows the driver there.  One other thing I can think of is possibly the BIOS enabling Secure Boot on its own, but that might be a long shot.

Comment: @Terrance based on the list of kernels and the new kernel (5.4) installed recently, replacing the old kernel shown also in dkms (4.15), I selected the 4.15 kernel on the grub menu and now everything works as before. The next step is to remove the new kernels and see how to avoid this from happening again. But you answered the question, as you provided a way of checking what was the problem. If you formulate it as an answer I can accept it.